# Event 'onsave' in rich:editor doesn't fire

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm implementing some kind of frontend editor in my web page, using `rich:editor`. When clicking a link, the editor should open, and after saving editor's content, the editor should close again. I'm having trouble with `onsave` event for closing the editor. Here is my code.

This is the link that **opens** the editor, due to setting the property `bean.show` to true. It works ok:

```
<h:commandLink>
    ...
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{bean.show}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

This is the editor itself, only rendered when `show` evaluates to true:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:editor value="..." onsave="showEditor(false)" rendered="#{bean.show}" />
</h:form>
```

The `onsave` event should **close** the editor by setting the `show` property to false again, but the editor stays open, because `showEditor()` is not called:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="showEditor">
    <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{bean.show}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Am I doing something completely wrong? Or do you have any other ideas how to realize this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just double-checked: in version richfaces 4.x, there is no `onsave` attribute at all, but

- oninit
- onblur
- onfocus
- ondirty
- onchange

like pointed out in the org.richfaces.component.UIEditor class. The same is true, if you want to use `f:ajax` to ajaxify the editor.

Right now, the "save"-icon in the editor just sends a `form.submit()` or something. So either try to add your jsFunction on that event or to introduce an own save-button.

**Edit:** Richfaces 4 uses the javascript based CKEditor, so if you want to overwrite their "save"-button, [this forum entry regarding CKEditor's save implementation](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Enable-save-button) might be of your help.

Also a `valueChangeListener` might be a possibility solution to trigger your `Bean.setShow(boolean show)` property.

xhtml:

```
<rich:editor value="#{bean.editorValue}" 
             valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChanged}" />
```

method in managed bean:

```
public void valueChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
   // do the code to close the window here
}
```

The `valueChangeListener` also works in Richfaces 4.3, but maybe starting within the javascript of the CKEditor is the better choice.

Hope, that helps... L.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately there's no `valueChangeListener` allowed in rich:editor component. I already checked this. Think I have to "overwrite" save() method as you suggested.

Comment: Strange, it works in Richfaces 4.3.1.Final ... added the source to the last comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I've tested was `setPropertyActionListener` (would have been nice if it had worked), but not valueChangeListener.

Comment: Well, so it seems you have a possible solution for the original problem. Would be happy about an upvote or a "solved", if the provided solution satisfies your needs... :-)